# Android: Recyclerview with hierachial data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have this POJO which is sort of recursive because it has a list object of itself (children) as shown below.

```
public class Volume implements Serializable, Parcelable {

    @JsonProperty("avail")
    private Long avail;

    @JsonProperty("children")
    private List<Volume> children = null;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    private Long id;

    @JsonProperty("is_decrypted")
    private Boolean isDecrypted;

    @JsonProperty("is_upgraded")
    private Boolean isUpgraded;

    @JsonProperty("mountpoint")
    private String mountpoint;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    private String name;

    @JsonProperty("path")
    private String path;

    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("used")
    private Long used;

    @JsonProperty("used_pct")
    private String usedPct;

    @JsonProperty("vol_encrypt")
    private Long volEncrypt;

    @JsonProperty("vol_encryptkey")
    private String volEncryptkey;

    @JsonProperty("vol_guid")
    private String volGuid;

    @JsonProperty("vol_name")
    private String volName;
}
```

Is it possible to display it's children regardless of depth/level in the same list/level as the parent? If so, how can I do this.

I already have built the code using the normal adapter like so.

```
private class VolumeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VolumeAdapter.VolumeHolder> {

    private List<Volume> volumeList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public VolumeHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new VolumeHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_volume, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(VolumeHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.volume = volumeList.get(position);
        holder.name.setText(holder.volume.getName());
        holder.mountpoint.setText(holder.volume.getMountpoint());
        holder.status.setText(holder.volume.getStatus());

        if (bytesManager.getLengthInGB(holder.volume.getUsed()).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
            if (bytesManager.getLengthInMB(holder.volume.getUsed()).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
                if (bytesManager.getLengthInKB(holder.volume.getUsed()).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
                    holder.used.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f %s (%s)", holder.volume.getUsed(), "B", holder.volume.getUsedPct()));
                } else {
                    holder.used.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f %s (%s)", bytesManager.getLengthInKB(holder.volume.getUsed()), "KB", holder.volume.getUsedPct()));
                }
            } else {
                holder.used.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f %s (%s)", bytesManager.getLengthInMB(holder.volume.getUsed()), "MB", holder.volume.getUsedPct()));
            }
        } else {
            holder.used.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f %s (%s)", bytesManager.getLengthInGB(holder.volume.getUsed()), "GB", holder.volume.getUsedPct()));
        }

        if (bytesManager.getLengthInGB(holder.volume.getAvail()).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
            if (bytesManager.getLengthInMB(holder.volume.getAvail()).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
                if (bytesManager.getLengthInKB(holder.volume.getAvail()).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) == 0) {
                    holder.avail.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f %s", holder.volume.getAvail(), "B"));
                } else {
                    holder.avail.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f %s", bytesManager.getLengthInKB(holder.volume.getAvail()), "KB"));
                }
            } else {
                holder.avail.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f %s", bytesManager.getLengthInMB(holder.volume.getAvail()), "MB"));
            }
        } else {
            holder.avail.setText(String.format(Locale.US, "%.1f %s", bytesManager.getLengthInGB(holder.volume.getAvail()), "GB"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return volumeList.size();
    }

    public class VolumeHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public final View view;
        public final TextView name, mountpoint, status, used, avail;
        public Volume volume;

        public VolumeHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            view = itemView;
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            mountpoint = itemView.findViewById(R.id.mountpoint);
            status = itemView.findViewById(R.id.status);
            used = itemView.findViewById(R.id.used);
            avail = itemView.findViewById(R.id.avail);
        }
    }

}
```

But I need to change this to support the child objects as well.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you try the answer posted? Can you please tell me if that works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the solution you need is a recursive function like the following.

```
private List<Volume> getAllVolumesInAList(Volume volume, List<Volume> volumeList) {
    if (volume.children == null || volume.children.isEmpty()) {
        Volume volumeToBeAdded = new Volume(volume);
        volumeList.add(volumeToBeAdded);
    } else {
        for (Volume vol : volume.children) {
            getAllVolumesInAList(vol, volumeList);
        }

        volumeList.add(volume);
    }

    return volumeList;
}
```

I have added a constructor in your `Volume` class to make it work as well.

```
public class Volume implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("avail")
    public Long avail;

    @JsonProperty("children")
    public List<Volume> children = null;

    @JsonProperty("id")
    public Long id;

    @JsonProperty("is_decrypted")
    public Boolean isDecrypted;

    @JsonProperty("is_upgraded")
    public Boolean isUpgraded;

    @JsonProperty("mountpoint")
    public String mountpoint;

    @JsonProperty("name")
    public String name;

    @JsonProperty("path")
    public String path;

    @JsonProperty("status")
    public String status;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    public String type;

    @JsonProperty("used")
    public Long used;

    @JsonProperty("used_pct")
    public String usedPct;

    @JsonProperty("vol_encrypt")
    public Long volEncrypt;

    @JsonProperty("vol_encryptkey")
    public String volEncryptkey;

    @JsonProperty("vol_guid")
    public String volGuid;

    @JsonProperty("vol_name")
    public String volName;

    public Volume() {
    }

    public Volume(Volume volume) {
        this.avail = volume.avail;
        this.id = volume.id;
        this.isDecrypted = volume.isDecrypted;
        this.isUpgraded = volume.isUpgraded;
        this.mountpoint = volume.mountpoint;
        this.name = volume.name;
        this.path = volume.path;
        this.status = volume.status;
        this.type = volume.type;
        this.used = volume.used;
        this.usedPct = volume.usedPct;
        this.volEncrypt = volume.volEncrypt;
        this.volEncryptkey = volume.volEncryptkey;
        this.volGuid = volume.volGuid;
        this.volName = volume.volName;
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!